# embedded Jetty9 + Websockets . onWebSocketText says i'm not connected

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm using Jetty 9.0.2.v20130417 in my app (under Java 1.7)

The Servlet:

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketCreator;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;

public class WSServletHandler extends WebSocketServlet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6600543852415589642L;

    public static class WSCustomCreator implements WebSocketCreator
    {
        @Override
        public Object createWebSocket(UpgradeRequest req, UpgradeResponse resp)
        {
            return new WSSocketHandler();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory)
    {
        factory.setCreator(new WSCustomCreator());
    }
}
```

The Websocket Handler:

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketAdapter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketException;


public class WSSocketHandler extends WebSocketAdapter
{
    public WSSocketHandler()
    {
        System.out.println("+++ Websocket class constructor");
    }

    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess)
    {
        System.out.println("+++ Websocket Connect from " + sess.getRemoteAddress().getAddress());   
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable e)
    {
        System.out.println("+++ Websocket Error " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
        System.out.println("+++ Websocket close " + statusCode + " , " + reason);
    }

    public void onWebSocketException(WebSocketException e)
    {
        System.out.println("+++ Websocket Exception " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketBinary(byte[] payload, int offset, int len)
    {
        System.out.println("+++ ignoring binary message");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message)
    {
        System.out.println("+++ MESSAGE: " + message);

        if (isNotConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("+++ not connected");
            return;
        }

        try {
            getRemote().sendString("lallo");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I can connect from javascript to the Jetty Server, and i can send a message from js to jetty. I see this message in the onWebSocketText function.
The problem: isNotConnected() is always true so nothing goes back to the Browser.
I dont get any errors in Jetty or Javascript in the Browser.

Jetty Logs: http://pastebin.com/Qq2EynFJ

I'm running out of ideas... i'm quite sure i miss something essential, but:
i have a similar test under java with exactly the same versions of jetty and java where this is working. The only difference is that the code above is part of a larger application whereas the short test is a standalone program.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you do in `WSCustomCreator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you defined `isNotConnected` method, but you can do something like this based on your example.

```java
public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess){
        System.out.println("+++ Websocket Connect from " + sess.getRemoteAddress().getAddress());  
        this.session=sess;
}

 public void onWebSocketText(String message){
    if(this.session.isOpen()){
    }
}
```

Comment: the [isNotConnected](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-websocket/websocket-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/WebSocketAdapter.java#L47-L51) comes from WebSocketAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Doua is right.

If i get rid of onWebSocketConnect, everything is working.

when using onWebSocketConnect, you have to save Session somewhere (as Joakim showed in the first answer). After that, you have to use this.sess.
e.g.
this.sess.getRemote().sendString
or
this.sess.isOpen()

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the parent's implementation for onWebSocketConnect inside the method

```
public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session){
     // your code here
     super.onWebSocketConnect(session);   
}
```